# Sequelize Insert Cascade hasMany

Tags: javascript, node.js, model, sequelize.js, mysql2

Here again now having problem to insert hasMany.
tables Bill > BillDetail, im using freezeTableName: true to keep table in singular way

Relations from Bill Model

```
Bill.associate = (models) => {
  Bill.hasMany(models.BillDetail, { foreignKey: "idBill" });
};
```

This is the code to insert Bill and create BillDetail with Bill "id", but ignore BillDetails unless i add Bill.belongsTo BillDetail but i will insert just the first object of BillDetail

```
Bill.create({
    idClient: 1,
    description: "new project",
    BillDetail: [
      { idService: 1 }, 
      { idService: 2 }
    ],
  },
  { include: BillDetail });
```

im following the guide, but i don't know what im missing.
https://sequelize.org/master/manual/creating-with-associations.html

Answer (score 0):

You indicated `include` model with single name but you need to indicate with plural:

```
Bill.create({
    idClient: 1,
    description: "new project",
    BillDetails: [
      { idService: 1 }, 
      { idService: 2 }
    ],
  },
  { include: BillDetail });
```

compare with the example from the docs:

```
Product.create({
  id: 1,
  title: 'Chair',
  tags: [ // pay attention there is **tags** and not **tag**
    { name: 'Alpha'},
    { name: 'Beta'}
  ]
}, {
  include: [ Tag ]
})
```

Comment: im using property "freezeTableName:true" to handle singular way

Comment: This option is not about that issue.